# NoSuchMethod error when running appium tests

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium

I am facing this error when I try to run appium tests:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.HttpClient$Factory org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.HttpClient$Factory.createDefault()'
```

Below are my desired capabilities.
I am trying to launch tests on a browser stack cloud device.

This is my pom.xml:

```xml
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();

HashMap<String, Object> browserstackOptions = new HashMap<String, Object>();
browserstackOptions.put("userName", browserStackUserName);
browserstackOptions.put("accessKey", browserStackKey);
browserstackOptions.put("projectName", "YardApp");
browserstackOptions.put("buildName",
        scenario.getName() + "-" + Generic.getDateTimeWithPlusMinutes(0, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"));
browserstackOptions.put("idleTimeout", "300");
browserstackOptions.put("acceptInsecureCerts", "true");
browserstackOptions.put("debug", "true");

// Capabilities
caps.setCapability("bstack:options", browserstackOptions);
caps.setCapability("platformName", "android");
caps.setCapability("deviceName", device);
caps.setCapability("os_version", version);
caps.setCapability("app", "bs://e67f6ce172b4de8e8d532fca41c0831c9a09f4f5");

// Instantiate Appium Driver
try {
    // driver.mobileInstance = new AndroidDriver(new URL("https://" +
    // browserStackUserName + ":"
    // + browserStackKey + "@hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub"), caps);

    driver.mobileInstance2 = new AppiumDriver(new URL(
            "http://" + browserStackUserName + ":" + browserStackKey + "@hub-cloud.browserstack.com"),
            caps);

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

I have tried with different combinations of appium and selenium but nothing seems to be working.